# Check Android Browser console log

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser

So I have a website using Javascript which works on all browsers except the Android browser.

I know I can enable Javascript debugging with `about:debug` but I have no idea where I can check the console log/errors.

How I can check my browser console for errors in the Android browser?

Answer (score 1):

Reni.

**EDIT:**

In that case:

1. Open Stock browser (Not Chrome on ICS. about:debug doesn't work in
   Chrome. Use remote debugging instead.)
2. In the address bar, type
   about:debug, nothing should happen, there will be no confirmation
   screen or flashing green box telling you that you've done anything.
3. However, there should now be a few new options in the browser's
   Settings page.

This will show you errors that even window.onerror doesn't catch, which should help you narrow down your problem(s).

Have a good day!

Comment: Keyboard? I'm talking on Android, no Ctrl, no Shift, no J